# File validation failed. Upload Images magento 2

Tags: magento2, cms-block

Getting an error `File validation failed.` when trying to upload JPG format images from cms block in Magento 2.3 version. File Path : `vendor/magento/module-cms/etc/di.xml`

```
    <argument name="extensions" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="allowed" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="jpg" xsi:type="string">image/jpg</item>
            <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="string">image/jpeg</item>
            <item name="png" xsi:type="string">image/png</item>
            <item name="gif" xsi:type="string">image/gif</item>
            <item name="svg" xsi:type="string">image/svg+xml</item>
        </item>
        <item name="image_allowed" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="jpg" xsi:type="string">image/jpg</item>
            <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="string">image/jpeg</item>
            <item name="png" xsi:type="string">image/png</item>
            <item name="gif" xsi:type="string">image/gif</item>
            <item name="svg" xsi:type="string">image/svg+xml</item>
        </item>
        <item name="media_allowed" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="flv" xsi:type="string">video/x-flv</item>
            <item name="swf" xsi:type="string">application/x-shockwave-flash</item>
            <item name="avi" xsi:type="string">video/x-msvideo</item>
            <item name="mov" xsi:type="string">video/x-sgi-movie</item>
            <item name="rm" xsi:type="string">application/vnd.rn-realmedia</item>
            <item name="wmv" xsi:type="string">video/x-ms-wmv</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
```

Comment: then you should debug in `checkMimeType()` function in `vendor/magento/framework/File/Uploader.php.` and print `$this->_getMimeType()` to see which mimeType you get for your image.

Comment: private function _getMimeType()
    {
        return $this->fileMime->getMimeType($this->_file['type']);
    }

Comment: i am doing this getting error like Attention

File 'image/jpeg' doesn't exist

Comment: like this:public function checkMimeType($validTypes = [])
    {
        echo $this->_getMimeType();die;
        if (count($validTypes) > 0) {
            if (!in_array($this->_getMimeType(), $validTypes)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

and check in inspect element netowork xhr

Comment: A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later.

Comment: getting error after adding this line

Comment: have checked inspect element > network > your xhr request > response tab?
https://prnt.sc/mip8nd
https://prnt.sc/mip8q7

Comment: debug like this: https://prnt.sc/mip8nd    && https://prnt.sc/mip8q7

Comment: did you get any response?

Comment: {"error":"File 'image\/jpeg' doesn't exist","errorcode":0}

Comment: check this link : https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/16531/#issuecomment-404671271

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to upload svg image and you have allowed  `<item name="svg" xsi:type="string">image/svg+xml</item>` in `vendor/magento/module-cms/etc/di.xml` file and still you are getting error `File validation failed.` then you need to check which MimeType you get for your uploaded image in `public function checkMimeType()` of this file: `vendor/magento/framework/File/Uploader.php`. In my case i get `image/svg` so i need to added `<item name="svg" xsi:type="string">image/svg</item>` instead of `<item name="svg" xsi:type="string">image/svg+xml</item>`. If this works then you can override `vendor/magento/module-cms/etc/di.xml` file.

If still not work and getting `{"error":"File 'image\/jpeg' doesn't exist","errorcode":0}`  in response then check this link: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/16531/#issuecomment-404671271

Comment: i am upload jpg image

Answer (score 3):

I have experienced the same issue. After installing "**PHP Fileinfo module**" it works. The issue is fixed.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I was able to track my problem to Magento/Framework/File/Uploader.php:

```
private function _getMimeType()
     {
          return $this->fileMime->getMimeType($this->_file['tmp_name']);
     }
```

The temporary file name stored in $this->_file['tmp_name'] does not have an extension so Mime type returned will not be correct. I was able to solve my issue by going back and use

`return $this->_file['type'];`

see https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/File-validation-failed/td-p/102830

Answer (score 1):

Try following code:

```
    <arguments>
        <argument name="extensions" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="allowed" xsi:type="array">

                <item name="jpg" xsi:type="string">image/jpg</item>
                <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="string">image/jpeg</item>
                <item name="png" xsi:type="string">image/png</item>
                <item name="gif" xsi:type="string">image/gif</item>
                <item name="svg" xsi:type="string">image/svg+xml</item>
            </item>
            <item name="image_allowed" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="jpg" xsi:type="string">image/jpg</item>
                <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="string">image/jpeg</item>
                <item name="png" xsi:type="string">image/png</item>
                <item name="gif" xsi:type="string">image/gif</item>
                <item name="svg" xsi:type="string">image/svg+xml</item>
            </item>
            <item name="media_allowed" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="flv" xsi:type="string">video/x-flv</item>
                <item name="swf" xsi:type="string">application/x-shockwave-flash</item>
                <item name="avi" xsi:type="string">video/x-msvideo</item>
                <item name="mov" xsi:type="string">video/x-sgi-movie</item>
                <item name="rm" xsi:type="string">application/vnd.rn-realmedia</item>
                <item name="wmv" xsi:type="string">video/x-ms-wmv</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
```

Hope this will be working.

Answer (score 1):

"ico" type is associated with "image/vnd.microsoft.icon", This is the part that is not recognized when we upload our ICO file.

In vendor\magento\module-media-storage\Model\File\Validator\Image.php,

replace

```
“image/vnd.microsoft.icon”
```

to

```
“image/x-icon”
```

But, this is the core file, so you need to override the file or create patch for it.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases we have to use `return true;`,

after using `return $this->_file['type'];` in the function

```
public function checkMimeType($validTypes = [])
    {
        if (count($validTypes) > 0) {
            if (!in_array($this->_getMimeType(), $validTypes)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this for us by changing the image adapter

In Magento Admin go to
Stores > Configuration

Under the Advanced Tab > Developer

You will see Image Processing Settings this was set to PHP GD2

Changing this to ImageMagick allowed me to upload png images